# Is there a way to convert BAK using R?

Tags: r, sql-server, database

Is there a way to use R to convert a BAK file to something more usable? I do not know of a library to do this, or if I could even do it using native R.

I saw on [this website](https://sqlbak.com/blog/open-a-bak-file), that I could use SQL Server Management Studio to do this; but I am trying to not install extra software on this machine.

This may not be currently supported, but I wanted to ask before installing additional software. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: (1) Asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"* is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (2) Unless I'm mistaken, a `.bak` file provides no indication of what is actually in it, it's just a convention for backing up **some file**. Because of that, there is absolutely no way we can know how to convert the `.bak` file without knowing more about its contents. If you don't *know* what the file is supposed to be, then in a mac/linux terminal you can do `file abc.bak` and it might tell you something informative about it. (Or edit it, see for yourself.)

Comment: The BAK file is for a Microsoft SQL Server. This is indicated in the article I linked, and the part where I mention "SQL Server Management Studio"as a means of restoring it. More directly, I am looking to get the BAK into a format that can be read by R Studio Connections.

Comment: Okay. Nothing in that article suggests the format of the file (other than something SSMS can infer, even the article says *"depending on the type of backup file that it is"*). If it is a binary format, then I still say this is off topic, but regardless I've not heard of any R package that gives you access to that kind of file (I might be missing some, there are way too many packages to track them all).